# Python how to look for issue numbers in string?

Tags: python

**Primary Goal:**

Find version number of a specific file.

I am working on a project - I am not able to find anything similar to my problem. I have found that regex might help me, but it's very complicated. So looking for an easier method.

**Problem:**

I have variables like so:

```
a = 'Section 1 - Analyse (i01).docx'
b = 'Section 1 - All Vitamins (i02).docx'
c = 'Section 1 - (i03) Removed Vitamins .docx'
```

**Question:**

How can I look at what the number is inside `(i)` for individual variables above?

**Key:**

`(i01)` - `i` simply represents an issue number.

**Example:**

One example, the issue number `(i)` for variable `a` is `01`.

Another example, the `i` for variable `b` is `02`. This is because it looks for the `i` and shows the numbers next to the `i`.

**Notes:**

Does anyone know  to look at the version numbers within the variables and return the number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `re.findall`:

```
a = 'Section 1 - Analyse (i01).docx'
issue = re.findall(r'\(i(\d+)\)', a)
print(issue)
```

This prints:

```
['01']
```

The potential advantage of using `findall` here is that it would find all matches of issue numbers, should an input string have more than one match.

Comment: Thank you, do you mind explaining what is happening please? :)

Comment: Also, how can the output print as `01` without the `[]`?

Comment: `print(issue[0])`, although it'd be more appropriate if `issue` were called `issues` in this case

Comment: @LV98 This is a regex statement, if you paste it into https://regexr.com/ it'll explain each segment. `re.findall` returns a list of all matches, so you'll need to select just the first element.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick throw-away script something like this would work:

`v_number = input.split('(i')[1].split(')')[0]`

This is using the `split` function to convert the string into a list of strings split by the supplied argument. The returned value will be a string.

Comment: The regular expression answer by @Tim Biegeleisen looks better